# Should int a, f() {} compile?

Tags: c, variable-declaration, function-declaration

for a typo, I leave the `a` in there. When I went to compile, the compiler reported:

> missing a ',' between declaration of 'a' and 'f'

code:

```
int a
f(void) 
{
}
```

And was very surpresing since I've never get any error message like this and I didn't know I could put a comma there and it just compiled fine(in more than one compiler I tested):

```
int a,
f(void) 
{
}
```

But of course it wasn't my intention but `int f(void){}` instead of. I give a try in another compilers but it didn't worked and reported a syntax error like this (in clang):

> error: expected ';' after top level declarator.

My question is: which one is correct? it should or shouldn't compile? what does standard says about that behavior?

I'm not going to use it since it's a bit ugly to put variable and functions split by comma (just like it is for a function prototype). I'm just curious.

**EDIT:** added `void` in function parameter. Actually I wanted to write a function with empty parameters

Comment: The former _seems_ to be valid C89, and the latter invalid. For C99, I'm pretty sure, both are invalid (and gcc refuses to compile with `-std=c99 -pedantic`). `int a, f();` (the latter being a function declaration (function taking unspecified number of arguments returning `int`) without definition) however, would be valid C99. Which standard are you interested in?

Comment: Nice to know, I'll remove my comment, as it really doesn't mean to say any more than yours did, but somehow in the re-reading, you said it more cleanly than I.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it should not compile

You need

```
int a;
void f(void)
{
}
```

the voids are not the most important part at this moment in time.  The most important part is that you didn't put a semicolon after a.

When you don't put a semicolon after `int a` the compiler keeps reading in the next lines as part of the `int` declaration, so it didn't detect that you had two things you wanted, but rather one very weird thing like

```
int a f() { }
```

By adding a comma, you still didn't fix the issue; because, a comma indicates a list which would be a valid way to declare a list of integers

```
int a, b;
```

is valid while

```
int a, f() { }
```

is not because `f() { }` is not a valid name for an integer.  Characters like that might be valid in other places, but the preceding `a,` prevents it from being a valid there either.  The combination of what was meant to be two lines prevents it from being valid C.

But by adding a semicolon, now you get two sensible things in C.

```
int a;
f() { }
```

I highly recommend that every function you write has a return value, even if it returns nothing.

```
int a;
void f() { }
```

and again, it is a very good practice to explicitly indicate that the function doesn't take any parameters, so

```
int a;
void f(void) { }
```

which is equivalent to

```
int a;
void f(void)
{
}
```

Comment: Is this `C89` function definition?

Comment: C99 doesn't allow an empty declaration at file scope (as in your two second-last examples, the `;` after the closing `}` of `f`'s function body). And you're talking about _declarations_, not statements (there aren't statements at file scope).

Comment: @FiddlingBits: `void f() { }` is a valid function definition in C89/C90, in C99, and in C11. In all three versions of the language, `void f(void) { }` is preferred. (The `void` keyword and prototype syntax were introduced in C89.)

Comment: I'll add in the parameter void, best to not let old practices harm the new programmers.

Answer (score 4):

That would be a syntax error. The syntax for a function definition is

```
//        int             f()                                {}
declaration-specifiers declarator declaration-list[opt] compound-statement
```

There's no room for `a,` before `f()` (I'm basing this on a random C11 draft). For C89 it looks similar, except that `declaration-specifiers` is optional (because of the implicit-int rule).

Answer (score 0):

The language grammar does not allow for a function *definition* to appear as part of a *declaration*<sup>1</sup>. What you *can* do is write

```
int a, f(void);
```

because this is only a *declaration* for `f`.

---

<sup>1. That is, there's no path from the *declaration* non-terminal to the *function-definition* non-terminal; see Appendix A of the [online C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)</sup>